# Ways to share your screen in an automated script with chrome driver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

Using Python 3.7 and the latest chrome driver. 
I'm trying to use google meet to share my screen using Selenium's chomedriver, but I keep getting the error "your browser can't share your screen", no matter of the options I give the driver.

I tried disabling gpu and hardware accelerations as I saw in similar questions but nothing changes.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

I expect there is a way to automatically share my screen with a script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After submmitting a bug report at the chromedriver devs they answered a solution.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2905

> By johnchen:
>
> Some Chrome features don't work properly in a test environment. For
>   this particular case, you can work around by removing the switch that
>   tells Chrome it's running a test. If you're using Python, you need to
>   add:
>
> ```
> opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
> opt.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['test-type'])
> ```
>
> In Java, you can use
>
> ```
> ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
> opt.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[] { "test-type" });
> ```